# Querying a Full Text Search Table in Android Room Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, full-text-search, android-room

I am trying to create a search functionality in my app using Android's Room library **fts4** .
For some reason the queries always return an empty result.
And I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.
Below is my DAO and Entity data classes.
Am I doing something wrong here?

```
@Dao
interface HymnDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM hymns_table")
    suspend fun getAllHymns(): List<HymnEntity>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM hymns_table WHERE :id = _id ")
    suspend fun getHymn(id: Int): HymnEntity

    @Query(
        """SELECT hymns_table.* 
                 FROM hymns_fts 
                 JOIN hymns_table ON (hymns_fts.rowid = _id )
                 WHERE hymns_fts MATCH :query """
    )
    suspend fun search(query: String): List<HymnEntity>
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "hymns_table")
data class HymnEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val lyrics: String,
)

@Entity(tableName = "hymns_fts")
@Fts4(contentEntity = HymnEntity::class)
data class HymnFts(
    val title: String,
    val lyrics: String
)
```

Comment: `WHERE hymns_fts MATCH :query` -- this specifies a table, not a column. Are you sure that is valid syntax?

Comment: I thought it was supposed to match the given query.

Comment: At least that's what I understand from the google talk "The Room in the house". Correct me if  I'm wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare if table is specified then all occurrences, irrespective of column, will be   returned. See https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#simple_fts_queries e.g. it includes `SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'sqlite';`

Answer (score 1):

**Additional**

Considering the comment:-

> It turns out, it was because I was using a prepopulated database.

Here's an example based upon the answer above BUT with a suitable pre-populated database.

By suitable, one that is created based upon what Room expects which is itself based upon the Entities.

- **Note** as the original answer was used to provide another answer the database contains additional tables and indexes.

Creating a suitable database is made relatively easy as if you compile the project (CTRL+F9) with the Entities and the @Database (referring to the appropriate Entities), then Room generates java (Android View shows this). The file named the same as the @Database class suffixed with _Impl has a method called `createAllTables` which is the SQL that can be used quite easily in whatever SQLite tool (assuming the tool supports FTS).

**Creating the suitable Pre-Populated Database**

1. In Android Studio locate generated java file **TheDatabase_Impl** and the `createAllTables` method therein :-

[image]

2. using you SQLite tool basically copy the SQL from the generated java e.g.

:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hymns_table` (`_id` INTEGER, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `author` TEXT NOT NULL, `lyrics` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`));
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hymns_fts` USING FTS4(`title` TEXT NOT NULL, `lyrics` TEXT NOT NULL, content=`hymns_table`);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_hymns_fts_BEFORE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON `hymns_table` BEGIN DELETE FROM `hymns_fts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_hymns_fts_BEFORE_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON `hymns_table` BEGIN DELETE FROM `hymns_fts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_hymns_fts_AFTER_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON `hymns_table` BEGIN INSERT INTO `hymns_fts`(`docid`, `title`, `lyrics`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`title`, NEW.`lyrics`); END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_hymns_fts_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `hymns_table` BEGIN INSERT INTO `hymns_fts`(`docid`, `title`, `lyrics`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`title`, NEW.`lyrics`); END;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application_table` (`id` INTEGER, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_application_table_name` ON `application_table` (`name`);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brand_table` (`id` INTEGER, `path` TEXT NOT NULL, `code` TEXT NOT NULL, `value` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Model` (`id` INTEGER, `path` TEXT NOT NULL, `code` TEXT NOT NULL, `value` TEXT NOT NULL, `brandCreatorId` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`), FOREIGN KEY(`brandCreatorId`) REFERENCES `brand_table`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_Model_brandCreatorId` ON `Model` (`brandCreatorId`);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationBrandCrossRef` (`appId` INTEGER NOT NULL, `brandId` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`appId`, `brandId`), FOREIGN KEY(`appId`) REFERENCES `application_table`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`brandId`) REFERENCES `brand_table`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_ApplicationBrandCrossRef_brandId` ON `ApplicationBrandCrossRef` (`brandId`);
```

- Note don't include the SQL that creates the `room_master_table` or inserts the row into the table.

3. populate the database in the SQLite tool (to do this for the example 2 rows were inserted) e.g.

:-

```
INSERT INTO `hymns_table` (title,author,lyrics) VALUES
    ('All things bright and beautiful','Fred','All things bright and beautiful,\nAll creatures great and small,\nAll things wise and wonderful:\nThe Lord God made them all.\nEach little flower that opens,\nEach little bird that sings,\nHe made their glowing colors,\nHe made their tiny wings.\n'),
    ('Onward Christian Soldiers','Mary','Onward, Christian soldiers, marching as to war,\nWith the cross of Jesus going on before.\nChrist, the royal Master, leads against the foe;\nForward into battle see His banners go!\nblah the great')
;
```

- 2 rows added `All things bright and beautiful` and `Onward Christian Soldiers` (the latter having the extra line *blah the great*, so both have a common word)

4. Save/Close the database, open it again and save to make sure that it has been saved.
5. In the project create the assets folder and copy the database file(s) (if the -wal and -shm files exists (they shouldn't if the database has been closed)) into the assets folder.

- In the example the file is named `soanswers.db` as that's the connection I used.

e.g. :-

[image]

6. Amend the `Room.databaseBuilder` invocation to include the `.createFromAsset("the_filename_copied_into_the_assets_folder") method call.

e.g.

```
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java,"hymn.db")
                .createFromAsset("soanswers.db") //<<<<<< ADDED
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
```

7. All should be OK now.

---

In the example from the previous answer and after the steps above were taken, the code used in the activity was changed to :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getHymnDao()

    for(hymn: HymnEntity in dao.search("small")) {
        Log.d("HYMNINFOR1","Hymn is ${hymn.title}")
    }
    for(hymn: HymnEntity in dao.search("on")) {
        Log.d("HYMNINFOR2","Hymn is ${hymn.title}")
    }
    for(hymn: HymnEntity in dao.search("great")) {
        Log.d("HYMNINFOR3","Hymn is ${hymn.title}")
    }
```

The **Result** output to the log :-

```
2021-08-11 11:08:44.691 D/HYMNINFOR1: Hymn is All things bright and beautiful

2021-08-11 11:08:44.693 D/HYMNINFOR2: Hymn is Onward Christian Soldiers

2021-08-11 11:08:44.694 D/HYMNINFOR3: Hymn is All things bright and beautiful
2021-08-11 11:08:44.694 D/HYMNINFOR3: Hymn is Onward Christian Soldiers
```

i.e. The first two invocations of the query find the match that is unique to the hymn, the third matches both hymns (hence why great wass added to Onward Christian Soldiers).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that the FTS Entity MUST have a val/var for the **rowid** column that an FTS table has. The val/var can be named otherwise BUT only if `@ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")` is used. The rowid must also be annotated with @PrimaryKey.

- As per [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#populating_fts_tables) > *As well as the columns named by the user (or the "content" column if no module arguments were specified as part of the CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statement), each FTS table has a "rowid" column.*
- and [Android Developers - FTS4](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Fts4) > *An FTS entity table always has a column named rowid that is the equivalent of an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY index. Therefore, an FTS entity can only have a single field annotated with PrimaryKey, it must be named rowid and must be of INTEGER affinity. The field can be optionally omitted in the class but can still be used in queries.*

e.g. :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "hymns_fts")
@Fts4(contentEntity = HymnEntity::class)
data class HymnFts(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid") // not required in this case but doesn't hurt
    val rowid: Long, //<< Required for FTS
    val title: String,
    val lyrics: String
)
```

**Working Example**
using the above along with your code (*modified slightly for my quirks*) then the following (run on main thread for brevity and convenience) then :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: HymnDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getHymnDao()

        dao.insert(
            HymnEntity(title = "All things bright and beautiful", lyrics ="All things bright and beautiful,\n" +
                "All creatures great and small,\n" +
                "All things wise and wonderful:\n" +
                "The Lord God made them all.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Each little flower that opens,\n" +
                "Each little bird that sings,\n" +
                "He made their glowing colors,\n" +
                "He made their tiny wings.\n")
        )
        dao.insert(HymnEntity( title = "Onward Christian Soldiers", lyrics = "Onward, Christian soldiers, marching as to war,\n" +
                "With the cross of Jesus going on before.\n" +
                "Christ, the royal Master, leads against the foe;\n" +
                "Forward into battle see His banners go!"))
        for(hymn: HymnEntity in dao.search("small")) {
            Log.d("HYMNINFO","Hymn is ${hymn.title}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run **results** in :-

```
D/HYMNINFO: Hymn is All things bright and beautiful
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Mike.I'll give it a try and give you a feedback.

Comment: It turns out, it was because I was using a prepopulated database. But when I added a callback using the ``addCallback`` method I get this error ``SQL logic error or missing database (Sqlite code 1), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory``.Even after clearing the app data and uninstalling the app.

Comment: @EyramMichael that sounds/looks like it's the copy of the database file(s) failing because the databases folder (in data/data/package_name/) doesn't exist. Perhaps use  `createFromAsset` or `createFromFile` which should correctly handle the copy. See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createFromAsset(java.lang.String,%20androidx.room.RoomDatabase.PrepackagedDatabaseCallback)

Comment: @EyramMichael furthermore does the pre-populated DB include Triggers? Room expects the triggers (that Room Builds) to apply the deletes,updates and inserts into the HymnEntity table to the Hymns_fts table. If you compile and look at the generated java you can see that room creates the triggers as part of the `createAllTables` method. Without these are an equivalent then there will be nothing in the FTS virtual table.

Comment: The original database  doesn't include Triggers , room creates the triggers in the ``database_impl``file for me.

Comment: @EyramMichael they will not be created if the database exists, which it will, if it's prepopulated. As such the pre-populated MUST have the triggers or an alternative means of maintaining the FTS table.  See the additional answer.

Comment: I found this tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/14292824-full-text-search-in-room-tutorial-getting-started.The writer uses the same approach but my error appears when I add this line ``  db.execSQL("INSERT INTO launches_fts(launches_fts) VALUES ('rebuild')")
        }
      })`` to my code.

Comment: @EyramMichael Which says *However, Find My Launch ships with a database asset to pre-populate the application database when it is first created. **The pre-population process doesn’t trigger an update to the FTS index. Consequently, the index remains empty and returns zero results for every query.***

Comment: I'll give it a try.A and give you the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional parameter, like `title_search`, and, during fetching data or adding an element just map the value like:

```
list.filter { it.title_search = it.title.lowercase() }
```

Use query like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE title_search LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR description LIKE '%' || :querydescription || '%' LIKE :query")
    abstract suspend fun searchkItems(query: String): List<Item>
```

```
|| '%' means + "%" in java, so basically like in list.contains(value)
```

Instead of LIKE you can use GLOB.
Read more about it in documentation.
Diacritics letter are included everything works fine.